# Relationship between fractional Poisson kernel for a region and its complement

Tags: operator-theory, fractional-calculus

Given a region $\Omega \in \mathbb{R}^d$, consider the Poisson problem for the fractional Laplacian $(-\Delta)^{2s}$ with $s>0$. Given a function $g: \Omega^C \to \mathbb{R}$, what is the function $u: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
u =g & \in \Omega^C \\
(-\Delta)^{2s}u = 0 & \in \Omega
\end{cases}$$

The restriction of $u$ to $\Omega$ can be found via integrating the Poisson kernel $P_{\Omega,s}:\Omega^C\times \Omega\to \mathbb{R}$. $$u(x) = \int_{\Omega^{C}}P_{\Omega,s}(y,x)g(y)dy$$

I was investigating the relationship between $P_{\Omega}$ and $P_{\Omega^C}$.

In particular, I noticed that if $\Omega$ was a sphere or a half space that $P_{\Omega^C,s}$ is the analytic continuation of $P_{\Omega,s}$ (i.e. they have the same functional form with different domains). For exmaple: if $B$ is the unit ball, $P_{B}$ and $P_{B^C}$ both have the form

$$\frac{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})\sin(\pi s)}{\pi^{\frac{d}{2}+1}} (\frac{1-|y|^2}{|x|^2-1})^s\frac{1}{|x-y|^d}$$

Is this always true or simply a quirk of these particularly symmetric cases?

Any other references about the relationship between the Poisson kernels of complementary sets would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case if you consider the fractional Laplacian on $\mathbb{R}$, $s\in(1/2,1)$ and the region $\Omega=(-1,1)$.

You may compare the expressions for the Poisson Kernel of $\Omega^c$ in Theorem A vs the Poisson kernel of $\Omega$ in Theorem C, both in
[Blumenthal, R. M., Getoor, R. K., & Ray, D. B. (1961). On the distribution of first hits for the symmetric stable processes. Transactions of the American Mathematical Society, 99(3), 540-554](https://community.ams.org/journals/tran/1961-099-03/S0002-9947-1961-0126885-4/S0002-9947-1961-0126885-4.pdf)

The probabilistic explanation of this is related to the recurrence properties of the symmetric $\alpha$-stable process (a Lévy process whose generator is the fractional Laplacian, with $\alpha=2s$).